# Count of occurence of a word in the column using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is how my text file looks like

```
000000005|19670905|M|20060201|20070131|6709055223085|01|PRINCIPLE|000021629633|ONYX
000000005|19740423|F|20060201|20070131|7404230424084|01|WIFE|000021629633|ONYX
000000005|19991028|F|20060201|20070131|9910280147084|01|DAUGHTER|000021629633|ONYX
```

I need to encounter the word `PRINCIPLE` and then provide the count of `WIFE` and `DAUGHTER`
here the count of `WIFE` is 1 and `DAUGHTER` is also 1 
these columns and rows have headers 
There are multiple entries like `000004` , `000008` etc

```
counts = data['gender'].value_counts().to_dict()
```

I did this to get the count of males and females. I was just trying out. I need a little help in how to go about this problem using python

I want something like

```
PRINCIPLE WIFE DAUGHTER
and below the counts
```

Comment: So need change `counts = data['gender'].value_counts().to_dict()` to `counts = data['another col'].value_counts().to_dict()` ?

Comment: I want the number of wife and daughter in this particular entry 00000005

Comment: What is `print (df.columns)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
 import pandas as pd 

# select the gender col 
gender = data[['gender']] 
# groupby to a new dataframe
counts = pd.DataFrame({'count' : gender.groupby(['gender']).size()}).reset_index()
```

if you want to add the first col "entries"

```
gender = data[['gender','entries']] 
# groupby to a new dataframe
counts = pd.DataFrame({'count' : gender.groupby(['entries','gender']).size()}).reset_index()
```

Example :

```
>>> print(d)
   entries     gender
0        5  PRINCIPLE
1        5       WIFE
2        5   DAUGHTER
3        6  PRINCIPLE
4        6  PRINCIPLE
5        6   DAUGHTER
6        7       WIFE
7        7   DAUGHTER
8        7       WIFE

>>> count = pd.DataFrame({'count' : d.groupby(['entries','gender']).size()}).reset_index()

>>> print(count)
   entries     gender  count
0        5   DAUGHTER      1
1        5  PRINCIPLE      1
2        5       WIFE      1
3        6   DAUGHTER      1
4        6  PRINCIPLE      2
5        7   DAUGHTER      1
6        7       WIFE      2
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works! Could you please explain me what exactly is happening in the statements you have written above.

Comment: yep, 
pd.DataFrame creates a new dataframe, with column 'count' which takes the count of values (size) of the group by(columns) of dataframe d. It's an aggregation. 
groupby is an important method of dataframes processing. you can groupby with mean, sum etc . I invite you to check the documentation : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html